# Error: Unable to access jarfile auth-api.jar - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to set environment based configuration. Have created 3 different Spring profiles that I will be using during app development.

I have created:

- `application-dev.yaml` (which should be default profile)
- `application-test.yaml`
- `application-prod.yaml`

When I am trying to run app locally using

`java -jar auth-api.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`

I am getting the following error:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile auth-api.jar`

This is how my folder structure looks:

[image]

Comment: If you are using command line , make sure you are on the correct path. May I know on what path you are running this command and what path is your project on ?

Comment: what's the current working directory? if it's the project root try java -jar target/auth-api.jar....

Comment: I am inside of my uth-api project. This is in my terminal: `MacBook-Air:auth-api myname$` @SarthakSharma so in my project root

Comment: @MarcStroebel this was it I had to add traget folder to class path. Can you plese make it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on your project root , then give this command `java -jar target/auth-api.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev` or you can navigate to the target folder and then give this command `java -jar auth-api.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was what I was looking for. I have one more thing to ask if you maybe know when I run my app with Docker using command `docker run -p  8085:8085 docker-auth-api` how do I now define to run certain profile? For example test?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was what I was looking for. I have one more thing to ask if you maybe know when I run my app with Docker using command `docker run -p  8085:8085 docker-auth-api` how do I now define to run certain profile? For example test?

Comment: So I assume you already have a docker file in your project. That dockerfile should have the instruction to run it with a profile. Something like this - ```ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","-jar","auth-api.jar"]```. Or one more easier way is this - ```docker run -d -p 8085:8085 docker-auth-api -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"```